# Paho mqtt subscribe

Tags: python, mqtt

```
    import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe 




while(True):
    m = subscribe.simple("Light/forvard", hostname="192.168.1.100",port=1883, auth = {"username":"skorpia", "password":"n-1"})
    print(m.topic)
    print(m.payload)
```

При любом раскладе payload остаётся неизменной вообще. Выводит b'0' всегда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в методе отправки значений.
Через MQTT Explorer это выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или через библеотеку Paho выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]